# How can I aggregate data from one polygon unit to another unit and weight this value based upon a population density raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I would like to calculate the socioeconomic status (SES) of a watershed (dark grey) by aggregating SES data available at the health authority unit.
[image]

And I would like to weight this calculation based upon a population density raster layer so that health authorities with larger populations within the watershed boundary are given more weight than those with small populations within the watershed boundary.
[image]

Comment: For clarity: The dark grey polygon is your watershed? Do you want to break up the watershed based on the population areas? Or are you wanting to weight the SES data within the watershed based on the number of people within each SES?

Comment: Yes, the dark grey polygon is the watershed and I do not want to break it up. I would like to weight the SES data within the watershed based on the number of people within the watershed from each SES group (health authority).

Comment: So far, I have come up with a method of calculating the population of each SES group within the watershed (by adding up the cells of the population density raster and then dividing by 1600 - the number of cells in 1 square km). I then multiply the population by the SES statistic, which is a percent, to get the number of low-income people. I can then add up those for each health authority in the watershed and divide that by the total population in the watershed to get a low-income % again. I am hoping there is a slightly more efficient way of doing this.